# Difference between overloading operator< and writing a comparator with the same logic?

Tags: c++, c++14, operator-overloading, comparator

What's the difference between overloading `operator <` and writing a comparator with the same logic? For example, I want to use `std::sort` in my class. I can write my own comparator or I can overload `operator <`. What should I do and why? (Usually I overload `<`.)

Comment: You can sort something with different criteria, a comparator is a little more explicit

Comment: And there isn't always a "default order" for the objects of every class. Forcing one upon the code in the form of `operator<` doesn't make sense.